# AAPT failed linking references

Tags: android, rom, aapt2

When I'm building the ROM, SamsungDoze gives me an error when AAPT is linking references:

```
[  0% 162/23367] AAPT2 link /home/javi...sungDoze_intermediates/package-res.apk
FAILED: /home/javi/RR/out/target/product/hlte/obj/APPS/SamsungDoze_intermediates/package-res.apk 
/bin/bash -c "(rm -f /home/javi/RR/out/target/product/hlte/obj/APPS/SamsungDoze_intermediates/aapt2-flat-list ) && (touch /home/javi/RR/out/target/product/hlte/obj/APPS/SamsungDoze_intermediates/aapt2-flat-list ) && (rm -f /home/javi/RR/out/target/product/hlte/obj/APPS/SamsungDoze_intermediates/aapt2-flat-overlay-list ) && (touch /home/javi/RR/out/target/product/hlte/obj/APPS/SamsungDoze_intermediates/aapt2-flat-overlay-list ) && (echo -n '/home/javi/RR/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v14-preference_intermediates/package-res.apk /home/javi/RR/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-recyclerview_intermediates/package-res.apk /home/javi/RR/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-preference_intermediates/package-res.apk /home/javi/RR/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-appcompat_intermediates/package-res.apk /home/javi/RR/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v13_intermediates/package-res.apk /home/javi/RR/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v4_intermediates/package-res.apk /home/javi/RR/out/target/product/hlte/obj/APPS/SamsungDoze_intermediates/flat-res/device/samsung/qcom-common/doze/res/values_styles.arsc.flat /home/javi/RR/out/target/product/hlte/obj/APPS/SamsungDoze_intermediates/flat-res/device/samsung/qcom-common/doze/res/xml_gesture_panel.xml.flat ' >> /home/javi/RR/out/target/product/hlte/obj/APPS/SamsungDoze_intermediates/aapt2-flat-overlay-list ) && (/home/javi/RR/out/host/linux-x86/bin/aapt2 link -o /home/javi/RR/out/target/product/hlte/obj/APPS/SamsungDoze_intermediates/package-res.apk -z --no-static-lib-packages --auto-add-overlay --manifest device/samsung/qcom-common/doze/AndroidManifest.xml -I /home/javi/RR/out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/package-export.apk -I /home/javi/RR/out/target/common/obj/APPS/org.lineageos.platform-res_intermediates/package-export.apk   --java /home/javi/RR/out/target/common/obj/APPS/SamsungDoze_intermediates/src --proguard /home/javi/RR/out/target/common/obj/APPS/SamsungDoze_intermediates/proguard_options --min-sdk-version 27 --target-sdk-version 27 --product default -c en_US,en_US,cs_CZ,da_DK,de_AT,de_CH,de_DE,de_LI,el_GR,en_AU,en_CA,en_GB,en_NZ,en_SG,eo_EU,es_ES,fr_CA,fr_CH,fr_BE,fr_FR,it_CH,it_IT,ja_JP,ko_KR,nb_NO,nl_BE,nl_NL,pl_PL,pt_PT,ru_RU,sv_SE,tr_TR,zh_CN,zh_HK,zh_TW,am_ET,hi_IN,en_US,af_ZA,am_ET,ar_EG,ar_XB,az_AZ,be_BY,bg_BG,bn_BD,bs_BA,ca_ES,cs_CZ,da_DK,de_DE,el_GR,en_AU,en_CA,en_GB,en_IN,en_XA,en_XC,es_ES,es_US,et_EE,eu_ES,fa_IR,fi_FI,fr_CA,fr_FR,gl_ES,gu_IN,hi_IN,hr_HR,hu_HU,hy_AM,in_ID,is_IS,it_IT,iw_IL,ja_JP,ka_GE,kk_KZ,km_KH,kn_IN,ko_KR,ky_KG,lo_LA,lt_LT,lv_LV,mk_MK,ml_IN,mn_MN,mr_IN,ms_MY,my_MM,nb_NO,ne_NP,nl_NL,pa_IN,pl_PL,pt_BR,pt_PT,ro_RO,ru_RU,si_LK,sk_SK,sl_SI,sq_AL,sr_Latn_RS,sr_RS,sv_SE,sw_TZ,ta_IN,te_IN,th_TH,tl_PH,tr_TR,uk_UA,ur_PK,uz_UZ,vi_VN,zh_CN,zh_HK,zh_TW,zu_ZA,normal,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi --preferred-density xxhdpi --version-code 27 --version-name 8.1.0   -R \\@/home/javi/RR/out/target/product/hlte/obj/APPS/SamsungDoze_intermediates/aapt2-flat-overlay-list \\@/home/javi/RR/out/target/product/hlte/obj/APPS/SamsungDoze_intermediates/aapt2-flat-list )"
warn: ignoring density 'hdpi-v4' for -c option.
warn: ignoring density 'xhdpi-v4' for -c option.
warn: ignoring density 'xxhdpi-v4' for -c option.
device/samsung/qcom-common/doze/res/values/styles.xml:33: error: resource layout/preference_category_material_settings (aka org.lineageos.settings.device:layout/preference_category_material_settings) not found.
device/samsung/qcom-common/doze/res/values/styles.xml:44: error: resource layout/preference_material_settings (aka org.lineageos.settings.device:layout/preference_material_settings) not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

I didn't touched any file of doze. In the terminal, I've just do "brunch hlte" and when is compiling with AAPT, gives me this error. Please, help me.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this file [https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_xiaomi_msm8996-common/blob/lineage-15.1/doze/Android.mk](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_xiaomi_msm8996-common/blob/lineage-15.1/doze/Android.mk#L27) on line 27.
It declares the path of the layouts needed. If you don't have this line in your device tree, add it. Then add the following line to your roomservice.
`<project name="LineageOS/android_packages_resources_devicesettings" path="packages/resources/devicesettings" remote="github" revision="lineage-15.1"/>`

repo sync and done.
You can also add it into a dependency file.